# Usage of ROracle generates Error in .oci.fetch(res, as.integer(n)) : ORA-01805:

Tags: r, roracle

I use ROracle to enhance data reading from Oracle to R.
PC and OS specs: i5, 8Gb, Win7 64bit, Oracle 12c (client 64bit), R (64 bit, 3.2.2), Rstudio

Current code as it is:

```
>install.packages('ROracle_1.1-12.zip', repos = NULL)
>library('ROracle')
>drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
>con <- dbConnect(drv, "USER", "PASSWORD", dbname='DB')
>x<-dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE")
>y<-fetch(x)
```

But some error has appeared:

> Error in .oci.fetch(res, as.integer(n)) : ORA-01805: ....

The point is that the error is not permanent. Somitemes it arises, sometimes it doesnt and the script is running Ok.
I would be very grateful for your help with such a case.

Comment: `fetch` has other argumets needed to get not all row. I think if you what get all table simly use `dbGetQuery`, May be problems in row number to `fetch`

Comment: May be problem in your timezone or datetime format in [Oracle](http://www.error-code.org.uk/view.php?e=ORACLE-ORA-01805&s=1447666572)

Comment: Well, considering datetime formats - I have in the initial records smth like
15/12/2014 00:00:00. But ROracle imported as 15/12/2014 02:00:00.
any idea how to solve such a discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have different TZ (server\client) try

`dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE,DBTIMEZONE FROM dual")`

> SESSIONTIMEZONE DBTIMEZONE

> 1          +03:00     +04:00

if you have different values  change TZ

```
dbSendQuery(con,"ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '+4:0'")
dbCommit(conn = con)

dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE,DBTIMEZONE FROM dual")
```

> SESSIONTIMEZONE DBTIMEZONE

> 1          +04:00     +04:00

May be it can help you

Comment: Tried to apply script offered but it did not help. well, if i am scripting non-date fields then everything seems to be ok. but error is generated by fields with data.
May be it is worth talking to DB admin to tune my oracle client?

Comment: Yes may be, I have same problem with configuration my ora client

Comment: I resolved the issue by reinstalling oracle client to the lateste version with help of DB administrator. And set up the latest version of ROracle package (how to install ROracle see details https://gist.github.com/jgilfillan/7b0281067ed9feb4a71c).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by reinstalling oracle client to the lateste version of the current server of the same 64 bit with help of DB administrator. And set up the latest version of ROracle package (how to install ROracle see details gist.github.com/jgilfillan/7b0281067ed9feb4a71c).